# android - how to filter out system apps from listview of applications

Tags: android, filter, categories, launcher

i was using a snippet of android code to learn how to launch apps and make a launcher but i cant figure out how to filter out the apps like faceunlock and facebok for htc sense and apps like that

```
public static List<ApplicationInfo> getInstalledApplication(Context context) {
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    Intent main = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    main.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    List<ApplicationInfo> apps = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(0);
    Collections.sort(apps, new ApplicationInfo.DisplayNameComparator(packageManager));
    return apps;
}
```

I know im probably something simple wrong but i just cant seem to find it please help and explain the answer so i can learn from it :p ill post more code if needed

Answer (score 0):

See code below:

```
List<ApplicationInfo> applications = getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(0);
for (int n=0; n < applications.size(); n++)
{
    if ((applications.get(n).applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 1)
    {
        //This is System application
    }
    else
    {
       //This app is installed by user
    }
}
```

Comment: every time I try to implement this method is just gives me an error on

Comment: applicationInfo.flags everything else seems fine but that one piece of code is just not going through for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind i found the answer after long searching so i decided to put it up to help others with the same problem

```
public static List<ApplicationInfo> getInstalledApplication(Context context) {
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    List<ApplicationInfo> apps = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(0);
    Collections.sort(apps, new ApplicationInfo.DisplayNameComparator(packageManager));
    Iterator<ApplicationInfo> it = apps.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        ApplicationInfo ai = it.next();
        if ((ai.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) {
            it.remove();
        }
    }
    return apps;
}
```

All i ended up doing is replacing the code i originally had for this one  and imported Iterator and filtered all the apps not needed :) hope this helps others to

Answer (score -1):

You can differentiate between system apps and installed apps using Flags available in Package Manager.

```
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
List<PackageInfo> availableActivities = manager.getInstalledPackages(0);

for(PackageInfo packageInfo : availableActivities) {

    if ((packageInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 1) {
        continue;
    }
    else {
        //Installed Apps
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Although the code may speak for itself providing some details would help improve the quality of your answer!